# How to fix java.io.IOException: Multiple merge bases

Tags: git, jgit

When I use `jgit` to complete `git pull` as follows:

```
git.pull().call();
```

It causes an Exception

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Multiple merge bases for:
  0479d50e9bcb14f197e1f703cb9d20ce402e38be
  e52e86d1977a42c934a939f04d63deb8eaeb38bf found:
  518a66929b4480a5bd25defc5fe643937fc16cfa
  513273d6f0327f41c914c7cd5573adeb7d396d8f
    at org.eclipse.jgit.merge.Merger.getBaseCommit(Merger.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.merge.Merger.mergeBase(Merger.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.merge.ThreeWayMerger.mergeBase(ThreeWayMerger.java:121)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.merge.ResolveMerger.mergeImpl(ResolveMerger.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.merge.Merger.merge(Merger.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.merge.ThreeWayMerger.merge(ThreeWayMerger.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.MergeCommand.call(MergeCommand.java:208)
```

I want to know why it shows `mutiple merge bases`?

I would like to know how to fix the error using just `Jgit` and not the command line git?

Comment: I have seen the link，But I don't know how to fix the error using just Jgit

Comment: @sinory: Please look into the linked question again and the linked bug of jgit. robinst provided some information in his answer, too.

Answer (score 1):

The current stable release of JGit does not have the ["recursive" merge strategy](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_merge_strategies) yet.

But it is implemented in the development version (master branch) and will be released with 3.0, see the following commits and [bug 380314](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=380314):

http://git.eclipse.org/c/jgit/jgit.git/commit/?id=ab99b78ca08a6b52e9ae8b49afa04dd16496f2ac
http://git.eclipse.org/c/jgit/jgit.git/commit/?id=aa7be667bcca4bdb28b2485e28a05da54c431df7

So either build JGit yourself or download a snapshot build from the [Eclipse Maven repository](https://repo.eclipse.org/index.html#nexus-search;gav~org.eclipse.jgit~~~~).

If you use a build tool that supports Maven dependencies, use the following repository and artifact version:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>eclipse-jgit</id>
        <url>https://repo.eclipse.org/content/groups/jgit/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```